Unable to access resources/public/images from grails 5.3.6 and jdk 17
Unable to access resources/public/images from grails 5.3.6 and jdk 17
This is a plugin which resides under WEB-INF/lib
The files under resources should be accessible with the URL
http://localhost:1507/myapp/docgen/blue.png getting unable to read the file.

Grails version is 5.3.6 and Jdk version is 17
The application.yml
---
grails:
    profile: web-plugin
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: myapp.plugin.path
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    devtools:
        restart:
            exclude:
                - grails-app/views/**
                - grails-app/i18n/**
                - grails-app/conf/**
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
        upload:
            maxFileSize:    52428800
            maxRequestSize: 52428800
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
---                
grails: 
    resources:
        pattern: '/**'  
        
---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:prodDb;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
spring:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true


I'm expecting the files should be accessible as it was working with jdk8.
The error I'm getting is in postman
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light"/>
        <title>MyApp</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-ico" href="/myapp/assets/bundle/favicon-12d412c4caa125579dc8d528e9f70f3b.ico"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/assets/bundle/application-115e4e5cdb4826dc15c12d625e67916f.js" defer="defer" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/myapp/assets/bundle/main-43a890ac4f58067ab85545dc780d64e3.css"/>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        
            <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
            <div id="root"></div>
        
    </body>
</html>


A 500 usually is an unexpected error on the server side, which usually
results in error logging and stacktraces.  Please add those and if there
are none, ramp up the logging to get some.
